# How to implement layout like Palabre

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I've been trying to achieve layout like in the Palabre app. Here is the basic layout of that app:

[image]

Also I'm using this library from github:
[AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) but still unable to achieve the desired layout.

Can some one here guide me please.

Comment: You can simply create linear layouts with weights

Comment: @VivekMishra It is possible but I have to fetch different response from services in each cell and its a Grid View not only 6 cells. What you are suggesting would make Cell 1, Cell 2 and Cell 3 one single layout, then how would I parse data to those Cells?

Comment: If there will be more cells then using weights will not be a option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a list - use this awesome library to build staggered list.

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

if it is not a list ->

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Cell1"
            android:layour_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Cell2"
            android:layour_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
       <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Cell3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My requirement is of grid view.. but let me try out this library and get back to you.

Comment: I've test this library but still unable to achieve the desired look.. could you help me out on this, I'm just a newbie

Comment: update your quesion with what you tried with library